Rotate Object to align it to Z axis
I have a object that I need to separate per face and put them all flat on the floor,
I need to rotate the object based on a face normal that it will be oriented to the Z axis,
the issue is I dont know how to take this face as a reference and rotate it to a 0° on the Z faces


Do you need it to be multiple objects ? That kind of job can be achieved with geometry nodes, but it would be only one object.

Yes it is for 40+ faces, but If there is a solution for " one " object I can replicate ot for the others

My question was : do you need these objects to be separated ? Or is it okay if one object contains all the faces ?

sorry for the misunderstanding, no it can be on the same object

What should happen if faces aren't flat ? Quads and ngons don't guarantee to have flat faces.

GN - Flatten faces on XY plane
The nodes I'll present will separate faces, rotate them to align their normal to the Z-axis, and flatten them on the XY plane. You can ignore the Debug message block, only there to help you know what the nodes are doing to your mesh. There are 3 points to note :

You can disable the triangulation in the modifier panel, but it may generate distortions : if some faces aren't planar (quads/ngons), they will be distorded. The more flat is the face, the less distortion it will get. The warning is purely an estimation.
It guarantees that all normals are aligned to Z-axis (equivalently, face outside is pointing up, face inside is pointing down). But the rotation to get there is arbitrary. So, you may feel some faces seems to have rotated around the Z-axis compared to what you would expect.
Faces will overlap each other, I didn't attempt to spread them apart. Viewed from above, the face center will not move.



Separate non-tri faces into tris
Separate all faces with Split Edges (splits faces at the edges)
Store the face center position for later use
Rotate vertices around their facePosition, so that the normal is aligned with the Z-axis
Flatten faces on the XY plane, by forcing the z-position to 0. The previously mentioned distortion for non-tris happens here.
Will output a warning if Triangulate is disabled and if it appears some faces aren't planar (based on an estimation, you can tweak the Threshold of the Is Face Planar node. You can delete this blocks, only a debug tool to help you.

If you're lost with the nodes, you can Ctrl+Shift+click the nodes 1 to 5 to see what they output (maybe you need to have the Node Wrangler extension enabled). You can also ask me for more details if need be.
Output and blend file



wow thank you, it is prety awesome but, I'm sorry what I was looking for is way easier,
it was just rotating an object base on one of his face so that this face is oriented to the Zaxis, I dont need to oriented all the faces from this object to Z the W axis
I'm definitly gonna use your node but for another project!

@Felix Maison if the answer is correct mark it as such   ;)
